# Clear steps for uploading ios app with PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, apache, cordova

I **searched a lot** of questions about converting a HTML/CSS/Js project to a mobile app and most importantly how to submit it to stores. It would help me and for sure more others if someone can point out the exact steps one should make in order to submit an app to Appstore/Google Play and others. I built my app with Phonegap, i needed my `certificates` and `provisioning` profile and i finally got a `.ipa` file.

Is this file enough to submit my app to appstore for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not sure how much this post will be useful to you. But i m trying to brief you what we required to get our Cordova based mobile app certified in Apple iStore.

- Your ipa file
- Your app Name
- App description
- Screenshots - minimum 2 for iPhone 4, iPhone5, iPhone6, iPad
  (screenshots must be of proper resolution).
- Demo Video (optional).
- iTunes artwork image 512x512 png format (should be similar to App
  icon).
- App icon 1024 x 1024 pixels 72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency,
  no rounded corners, high-quality JPEG or PNG image file format.
- Supporting URL and Marketing URL (if any, for Apple to login into the
  app and verify)

Once you have all the above mentioned details, you will also need to have a apple developer account which costs you 99$ a year. You can login to the account and follow the upload wizard to complete your submission of the app to apple store for review.