# Replace existing app with another new app - IOS App store

Tags: ios, cordova

i have published an iOS app on app store developed by cordova. now i want to **replace** that **published iOS app with another new app** with xcode in another mac system. i hope you understand. is this possible to replace the old one?

Comment: Yes this is possible, you just need the right certificates/private keys

Comment: so i have to create new certificate and mobileprovision. or can i use existing certificate and mobileprovision on that new mac system .

Comment: You will have to use the existing signing certificates and provisioning which the live application uses

Comment: All you need is the bundle identifier, rest can be new (for same a/c) but the bundle identifier should be the existing one if you're updating the app

Answer (score 2):

You must have the access to itunes account which I think you might be having. Then add another version of your app in itunes and make an ipa of your new application with same app id and upload it to itunes and then submit it. Comment if you dont understand this or need screens hot for what I am saying

Comment: thanks for your answer. im going to develop a new app and upload from another mac system.so i just need to know whether i need to create new certicate and mobileprovision or old ios distribution and mobileprovision files are enough to do this stuff?

Comment: please share any screenshots if you have.

Comment: if you have your old mac then you can simply export your previous certificates from the keychain. If you dont then try creating new ones for the same app id

Answer (score 1):

Your statement "replace that published iOS app with another new app" is confusing. I guess you mean by updating the existing app or adding new app.

If you are questioning about adding a new app to app store for certification. That will be a new submission altogether where you may have to create a new bundle identifier but can make you use of the same developer certificate you have.

If you are questioning about updating an exising app which is already available in app store, you may have to create a new ipa with the same bundle identifier and resubmit it for the approval. Your old app will still be available in app store till the new updated app is approved in app store.

You can check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030803/clear-steps-for-uploading-ios-app-with-phonegap/36035686#36035686) for more info on uploading cordova app for apple ceritifcation.